# For Catholics who have expressed concern about Pope Francis and are wary of his pontificate, what are the key issues?

Tags: catholicism, pope-francis

Ever since his election on March 13, 2013, Pope Francis has [electrified the world](http://fortune.com/2014/03/20/fortune-ranks-the-worlds-50-greatest-leaders/) and is a media sensation

[image]

But among Catholics, who it is said tend to love their Popes to a fault, the reception of him is divided [cf. [Watch out Pope Francis: the Catholic civil war has begun](http://www.spectator.co.uk/features/9361502/watch-out-pope-francis-the-catholic-civil-war-has-begun/)]. This is by no means limited to Catholics among Christians (e.g. [Lee Duigon](http://newswithviews.com/Duigon/lee275.htm) , [Russell D. Moore](http://www.christianpost.com/news/what-should-evangelicals-make-of-the-rome-synod-on-the-family-128029/), and [Baptist Press](http://www.bpnews.net/43535/catholics-initial-report-not-in-line-with-scripture)).

For Catholics who have expressed concern about Pope Francis and are wary of his pontificate, what are the key issues?

Comment: The links you've provided in your question appear to provide answers to your question. I'm not sure exactly what you're hoping for. Are you wondering if someone has done a poll of Catholics to ask "What is your biggest complaint about the Pope?" and you're looking for the top answers?

Comment: @Flimzy I thought that was quite obviously what the question was about how else could it be interpreted?

Comment: I believe one of the biggest stumbling blocks is that he's a Jesuit.  The principles of the order would disqualify him from being Pope.  Furthermore, many have linked the Jesuits to those evil Freemasons, both with them and against them.  Quite confusing!  Nobody likes to be confused, so they keep things that cause confusion at arms length and just accept them

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User ... except for *"polling of Catholics."*

Comment: @FMS Apart from polling, how else you are going to get an idea of what problems the Catholic laity have with the current Pope and/or his policies? It seems to me the only way this question could be answerable. (By the way I'd be very keen to see an answer to this question - I think the current Pope is the best since at least Paul VI - but I'm an Anglican so I don't count.)

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Modeled the question after [this one](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/for-catholics-who-object-to-vatican-ii-what-are-the-key-issues). From your comment, perhaps another question for the site i.e. Catholics on the side of the divide, how they view Pope Francis and why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Catholics generally fall into three (not-necessarily-exclusive) camps regarding their questioning of Francis's orthodoxy and Catholicity:

There are those who recognize Francis as a promoter of

1. **[the errors and heresies of Vatican II](http://modernism.us.to/).**

   - Very few faithful have enough time to study and read to understand
     this (Abp. Lefebvre's short *[Open Letter to Confused Catholics](http://www.sspxasia.com/Documents/Archbishop-Lefebvre/OpenLetterToConfusedCatholics/index.htm)* is an
     excellent aid, though.), but the errors they identify are chiefly
     relativism of truth (i.e., [Modernism, the "synthesis of all heresies"](http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/pius_x/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-x_enc_19070908_pascendi-dominici-gregis_en.html)), from which follows

     1. ecumenism ([religious indifferentism](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Greg16/g16mirar.htm)),
     2. collegiality (that the body of bishops is a head of the Church alongside but not subjected to the Pope; viz., that the Church is governed by a two-headed monster…), and
     3. [religious liberty](http://www.christendom-awake.org/pages/thomas-crean/religious-liberty.htm) (the [Masonic idea](https://archive.org/stream/warofantichristw00dillrich#page/76/mode/2up) that man has a fundamental right to spread error and publicly practice false religions).
   - Most [sedevacantists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedevacantism) and [SSPX](http://sspx.org) adherents recognize this.
2. **error and heresy against faith.**

   - Many [traditionalist Catholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditionalist_Catholic)s recognize this.
   - e.g., Francis's [*Evangelii Gaudium* §247](https://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/apost_exhortations/documents/papa-francesco_esortazione-ap_20131124_evangelii-gaudium.html#_ftnref193) gives the heresy that the Old Covenant is still valid and that Jews don't need "to turn from idols and to serve the true God."
   - Francis

     1. saying "[there is no Catholic God](http://m.repubblica.it/mobile/r/sezioni/cultura/2013/10/01/news/pope_s_conversation_with_scalfari_english-67643118/)"
     2. supporting tritheism and atheism, saying "[God does not exist!…There is the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit!](http://www.novusordowatch.org/wire/francis-god-does-not-exist.htm)"
3. **moral errors.**

   - Even neocon [*Novus Ordo*](http://novusordowatch.org/) Catholics and some Protestants (e.g., conservative Evangelicals) see this.
   - e.g., the [mid-term report of the Synod on the Family](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PajgVWtgx1M#t=3m36s), which said there are goods in homosexuality. [Cf. this [RORATE CÆLI article](http://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2015/01/for-record-as-everyone-knew-pope.html): *Cardinal Baldisseri: the Pope was personally aware and personally approved the relatio post disceptationem*].
   - Francis dismissing the gravity of homosexuality by flippantly saying: "Who am I to judge?" ([interview full-text](http://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/full-transcript-of-popes-in-flight-press-remarks-released/))
   - [Francis demoting, without explanation, Cardinal Burke](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/breaking-its-official-cardinal-burke-removed-from-vatican-post), a strong defender of traditional marriage and the right to life of unborn people. (This was [the first time in over 50 years that a cardinal had been demoted](http://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2014/11/the-removal-of-great-cardinal-by.html?m=1).)
   - ["Dubia cardinals" accusing Francis of heresy against even moral norms](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/71731/1787)

#1 leads to #2 which, in turn, leads to #3. Most people, even Protestants, are now recognizing #3. Soon, it seems, more people will recognize #1 and #2 cause #3.

---

> <sup>**Note:**
>
>   A correspondent in Argentina [...] writes that only three
>   views of this pope exist:
>
>   1) he is a modernist, but covers himself by occasionally talking of the devil,
>
>   2) he seeks attention and power by attracting everything to himself, and
>
>   3) he is a confused thinker but basically orthodox.
>
>   The man adds that this last view is no longer tenable.
>
>   *Source:* [On Heretical Popes, *by James V. Schall S.J.* | The Catholic Thing](http://www.thecatholicthing.org/columns/2014/on-heretical-popes.html).</sup>