# Which U.S. bishops are unfaithful to Church teaching on homosexuality and LGBT ideology?

Tags: catholicism, homosexuality, united-states, bishops, lgbt

Which U.S. bishops are unfaithful to Church teaching on homosexuality and LGBT ideology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bishops unfaithful to Church teaching on

### [homosexuality](https://faithfulshepherds.com/issue/homosexuality/)

> The Catechism teaches that homosexual acts are intrinsically disordered. Persons who suffer from same-sex attraction are called by the Church to live chaste lives. Homosexual “marriages” undermine God’s plan for the family, which is oriented to the rearing and educating of children through the indissoluble union of one man and one woman.

- Cardinal Blase J. Cupich, Archdiocese of Chicago
- Bishop Robert W. McElroy, Diocese of San Diego
- Bishop Emeritus Patrick J. McGrath, Diocese of San Jose
- Archbishop Wilton D. Gregory, Archdiocese of Washington
- Archbishop John C. Wester, Archdiocese of Santa Fe

### [“LGBT” ideology](https://faithfulshepherds.com/issue/lgbt-ideoloy/)

> The so-called “Lesbian, Gay, Bi-sexual, and Transgender” agenda attacks the traditional understanding of man as created in the image and likeness of God. The Church draws its unchangeable teaching on sexuality from Scripture, which states that God created them “male and female.” Pandering to this ideology is harmful to the faithful and endangers souls.

- Auxiliary Bishop John P. Dolan, Diocese of San Diego
- Cardinal Kevin Farrell, Prefect of the Dicastery for the Laity, Family and Life
- Cardinal Joseph W. Tobin, Archdiocese of Newark
- Cardinal Blase J. Cupich, Archdiocese of Chicago
- Bishop Robert W. McElroy, Diocese of San Diego
- Bishop John Stowe, Diocese of Lexington
- Bishop James F. Checchio, Diocese of Metuchen
- Bishop Gerald R. Barnes, Diocese of San Bernardino
- Bishop Emeritus Patrick J. McGrath, Diocese of San Jose
- Archbishop Wilton D. Gregory, Archdiocese of Washington
- Archbishop John C. Wester, Archdiocese of Santa Fe

---

source: [*LifeSiteNews*](https://www.lifesitenews.com/)'s [Faithful Shephards](https://faithfulshepherds.com) initiative, which tracks the standing of bishops on many issues:

- Abortion politics
- [*Amoris Laetitia*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/71731/1787)
- Contraception
- Education
- [**Homosexuality**](https://faithfulshepherds.com/issue/homosexuality/)
- Liturgy
- Marriage and Family Life
- Pro-life leadership
- Viganò testimony
- [**“LGBT” ideology**](https://faithfulshepherds.com/issue/lgbt-ideoloy/)

Visit [Faithful Shephards](https://faithfulshepherds.com) to urge these bishops to convert.

Comment: You have not justified that all these bishops warrant being on such a list. Even the first one you list, Cupich, when you go to [his page](https://faithfulshepherds.com/bishop/blase-j-cupich/) to the section on homosexuality, is there anything that unambiguously shows he is unfaithful to the church's teaching? And if all the question does is reproduce the opinions of other website, I don't think that's a good use of this site.

Comment: @curiousdannii Are [list questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1532/1787) not allowed here?

Comment: List questions are problematic in general, but the bigger problem is that this answer appears to ultimately be opinion, not fact. Arguably it's even defamation.