# What are the divisions between Vatican I and Vatican II Catholics?

Tags: catholicism, vatican-ii

On this site Catholic questions are often answered very well by self avowed Catholics. Often two such users will argue well their viewpoints, but reach very different conclusions. For example see  as [Does the Catholic Church officially recognize Protestants as Christians?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/does-the-catholic-church-officially-recognize-protestants-as-christians)

In the comments, I have learned that there are adherents to the Church under a set of doctrines called Vatican I and another group adhering to Vatican II.

What are the major divides between the two and which group is the larger?

Comment: Vatican I defined [Papal Infallibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_infallibility). Vatican II was an [Ecumenical Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Vatican_Council). What is your question?

Comment: @ken Graham my question is do Catholics divide themselves over the acceptance and rejection of v1  v2

Comment: @kris Short answer is No. Vatican I was an ecumenical council convened for a particular  reason.  A more critical pre-Vatican II ecumenical council, in terms of doctrine and how the Church relates to the world, was the Council of Trent.

Comment: @KenGraham Vatican I was an ecumenical (i.e., general) council, too.

Comment: @korvinstarmast so there is a schism but not based on v1v2.  What is the nature of the schism that leaves 2 catholics having opposing doctrinal views

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Catholics who object to Vatican II, what are the key issues?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32008/1787).

Comment: @kris That's a separate question, which you may wish to ask, or you may wish to take a look at the link Geremia so kindly provided.  It is not IMO proper for me to try to answer since I was not Catholic before Vatican II, and the general tenor in our dioceses is that Vatican II happened, move forward!

Comment: @Geremia I am aware of that, but it had as its object far more internal matters than, for example, Trent. It also had the bad fortune to happen during the Italian civil war/Risorgimento which profoundly altered the Church's status, costing it the Papal states (and its status was not fully resolved until the Lateran Treaty).

Comment: You would be better off asking about the sedevacantist movement.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding a few of the issues; so let's get some background out of the way.

The First Vatican Council was an [ecumenical council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecumenical_council) of bishops of the Catholic Church held at the Vatican in 1870. A number of important issues were discussed, and some Church doctrine was formalized; perhaps the most important of these issues was **papal infallibility**. (Not all Catholics agreed with what the Church had stated about the Pope being, in certain circumstances, infallible; many of these broke away and established what's now called the Old Catholic Church.)

The Second Vatican Council, another ecumenical council, was likewise held at the Vatican between 1962 and 1965. A number of things were discussed here, largely relating to the Church in its relationship to the modern world. Several documents came out of the Council: many appeared, at least at first sight, to contradict things which had been accepted for years in the Church, even stated as dogma. [Answers to this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32008/12563) offer an overview of what the disagreements were and why they arose.

Unfortunately, neither those who accept not those who reject the teachings promulgated by Vatican II regard those on the other side as part of the true Catholic Church. It is reasonable to say, however, that far fewer than half a billion people (that is, half the number of people calling themselves Catholic) do in fact reject the Council and its teachings.

Comment: Not my greatest answer. I have time tomorrow morning to amend, but a good part of your question is answered in the one I linked.

Comment: As a suggestion, you might mention that there is no inherent contradiction between what Vatican I taught about infallibility and what Vatican II taught. In fact _Lumen Gentium_ has a great exposition and explanation of that dogma.

Comment: As this question has been closed as a duplicate (I'm not *positive* it is}, I'll leave my answer be.